# Displayport & HDMI KVM-Switch only show HDMI Connection but not DP

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, kvm-switch, docking-station

I have the following setup:

[image: Setup Diagram]

What works is the monitor plugged into the HDMI port on the KVM-switch, no matter which laptop I try it on.

What doesnt work is the displayport-monitor connection, no matter which laptop I try it on.

I have the following KVM-Switch:
https://amzn.eu/d/dZbH3PF

Both monitors work, when connected via HDMI to the KVM-Switch, but not via DP.
The DP to HDMI Adapter which is plugged into the KVM-Switch doesn't seem to be the problem because it works if I connect the monitor to the docking stations DP port with the adapter.

Any ideas how i can get that setup to work? I'm also open to the idea of replacing the existing hardware (cables and kvm switch) as it is brandnew so it can get refunded.

I'd be very grateful for a working solution, thank you!

Comment: From the reviews on the Amazon page you linked to, it seems that it only worked well for people who got a free sample of the product.